# Is there a control for displaying code branches in Qt?

Tags: qt, controls, pyqt4

I'm trying to display some kind of branches with Qt. How do I go about this? Will I have to draw it myself? Is there some control/thing that will do this for me?

[image: Example]
<sub>(source: [hades.name](http://hades.name/media/git/git-head.png))</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to do it yourself, use `QGraphicsScene` and `QGraphicsView`.

Answer (score 0):

To layout the graph, you may want to look at [GraphViz](http://www.graphviz.org/) - a graph visualisation tool.

You could just use the GraphViz algorithms for layout (using plain output) and then draw using the Qt libraries (`QGraphicsScene` / `QGraphicsView` like @cbamber85 recommended), or you could render a PNG from GraphViz and then display it.

You may want to look at [KCacheGrind](http://kcachegrind.sourceforge.net/html/Home.html), as this is a Qt application that uses GraphViz for laying out call graphs.